# How to initialize List with Task objects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

How can i initialize a List with Task objects (TPL) using C# and .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
        // Create tasks
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
        {
            new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("A")),
            new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("B"))
        };

        // Start them later
        tasks.ForEach(a => a.Start());
```

Or, if you want, start them at the moment of creation as Chad shown you (calling *Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)*.

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
     //do work
});
tasks.Add(task);
```

Comment: i want to define task with some action in it as well

Comment: can u do it in one line plz like List(){() => new action(//somework)} or similar

Comment: but this starts the task and then adds it.  I think what the OP wants is to add the task to list to start later.